# Gridview with button to add photo

Tags: android, image, button, gridview, photo-gallery

in my app i've to make a GridView for displaying some photos.

I need a button in the GridView to add a new photo to the same gridvew, 
like in this example:

[image: example gridview]

Is this possible? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible.

You have to add One Row item at last position in your data list (ArrayList or HashMap) and check for the last item in your customize adapter.

Comment: thanks,
but can you explain it better, if anything with an example, because is not very clear to me.

Comment: @Garumbo - As Paresh said, its something like manually adding 1 item (+) at d end of array of d adapter before setting to gridview and in onListItemClick(...) method for ex, check whether u clicked last item or nt by checking position then do any operation. After adding new element for ex, again u need to add that '+' item ad d end of d array so that it always comes last.

Comment: @Braj Thanks Braj for adding more info. It will sure show him a way for the issue.

Comment: Thank you both, I just tried to implement, and it seems that everything works. thank you!